# Adding shell access to existing users in zentyal

Tags: ssh, ldap, openldap

- I user ldap to create my user accounts. for every user created a home directory is created
- For every user created i have updated my configuration to adding a default shell. but i did this change post creating some users.
- For all existing users they are unable to login to server using ssh, as they dont have a default shell set. for all new users they were as the shell was set. how to fix so that existing users can access the shell.

Comment: so now u want to change the shell ? of existing user's & which Shell u want to give

Answer (score 2):

How to change the bash shell for existing users is explained [here](http://trac.zentyal.org/wiki/Documentation/Community/HowTo/SSHLoginAsEBoxUser)